# Append text after bars on horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working on a horizontal bar chart and I want to move the y-labels after the bar.

```
d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(data) {

    // Add X axis
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([ 0, width])

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .call(d3.axisTop(x).ticks(10).tickFormat(function(d){return d+ "%"}))
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10,-12)rotate(-45)")
        .style("text-anchor", "end");

    // Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([ 0, height ])
        .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.type; }))
        .padding(.5);

    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisRight(y))
        .selectAll('text')
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.number; } )

    //Bars
    svg.selectAll("myRect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", x(0.5) )
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.type); })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.number); })
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
        .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")

})
```

The CSV file has two columns

- type
- number

On this part of the code

```
  svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisRight(y))
        .selectAll('text')
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.number; } )
```

If I replace the line `.attr("x", function(d) { return d.number; } )` with
`.attr("x", 100 )` then it moves the labels towards right. But when I try to keep it dynamic by the width of the bar, the text stays a the start of the y-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, instead of creating a new selection with the labels as `<text>` elements, you're trying to move the axis' ticks! That's a quite uncommon approach, but it's certainly doable.

The main problem is just the data: in this line...

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return d.number; })
```

...the datum (`d`) is not the same datum that the rectangles have, which comes from your data. The datum here is just the strings in the axis' ticks.

Therefore, we have to get the real datum, so we can get the `number` value. Like this:

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
    const datum = data.find(function(e){return e.type === d})
    return x(datum.number);
})
```

Here is your code with that change (and some bogus data):

```js
var width = 500,
  height = 300,
  padding = 20;

var data = [{
    type: "foo",
    number: 42
  },
  {
    type: "bar",
    number: 12
  },
  {
    type: "baz",
    number: 79
  },
  {
    type: "foobar",
    number: 17
  },
  {
    type: "foobaz",
    number: 36
  }
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([padding, width - padding])

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,20)")
  .call(d3.axisTop(x).ticks(10).tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d + "%"
  }))
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,-12)rotate(-45)")
  .style("text-anchor", "end");

// Y axis
var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([padding, height - padding])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.type;
  }))
  .padding(0.5);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
  .call(d3.axisRight(y))
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    const datum = data.find(function(e) {
      return e.type === d
    })
    return x(datum.number) + 6;
  })

//Bars
svg.selectAll("myRect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", x(0.5))
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.type);
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.number);
  })
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
  .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```